# Can single dimension named vectors be created in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to name a vector with only a single column, i.e. say I have

```
vector<-c(1,2,3,4)
```

I want to name a single column of (1,2,3,4) as "a", i.e. I want something like:

```
a
1
2
3
4
```

If I try

```
colnames(vector)<- c("a")
```

It gives me output:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "a") : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

If I try

```
names(vector)<- c("a")
```

Vector is named as

```
    a <NA> <NA> <NA> 
   1    2    3    4
```

My question is if such a vector is allowed in R? Specifically, is this allowed without using a matrix or data.frame or any other such class which can store more than one columns? If yes, how do I create it?

Comment: Try `rep('a', length(vector))`

Comment: If you want it to be a *column*, perhaps you want to use `matrix` i.e. `m = matrix(1:4) ; colnames(m) = "a"`

Comment: Would you be OK with either a n x 1  matrix or a data.frame with only one column?

Comment: No my query is that is this allowed without using matrix or data.frame?

Comment: re your edit; to add a dimension to the vector (with rows & columns) will coerce it to a matrix (`v = 1:4 ; dim(v) = c(4,1) ; class(v)`. So I suspect the answer to your question is no, not without `matrix`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something with a column name and that will print in the column format then use a single column `matrix` or `data.frame`:

```
vector <- matrix( c(1,2,3,4), dimnames=list(NULL, "a") )

vector <- data.frame( a=c(1,2,3,4) )
```

There is a 1d object type but rather confusingly it requires that the assignment of a single dimension value to be its length. See:

```
  ?dim

dim(vector)=1L
Error in dim(vector) = 1L : 
  dims [product 1] do not match the length of object [4]

> dim(vector)=4L
> vector
[1] 1 2 3 4
> str(vector)
 num [1:4(1d)] 1 2 3 4
```

Actually the dim function help page doesn't appear to document the requirement that the product of the dim-result will equal the length. My guess is that your homework assignment was intended to get you to read the dim help page and then discover (as I just did) that a one-d object is possible but a bit confusing.

As it turns out the distinction between row and column vectors is not enforced:

```
> vector %*% matrix(1:16,4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   30   70  110  150
> t(vector) %*% matrix(1:16,4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   30   70  110  150
> t(vector) %*% matrix(1:16,4) %*% vector
     [,1]
[1,] 1100
> vector %*% matrix(1:16,4) %*% vector
     [,1]
[1,] 1100
```